# How to fix ' {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}' for Ajax GET request

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying build an `API` to insert data into my website (necessarily in different domains), but no matter how I format the response, my ajax calls fail to retrieve any data.

I have tried modifying the headers of the response, in particular to include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to avoid `CORS` problems. I also tried formatting the response as a `JSONP`, to no avail.

Here's a minimal piece of code that I can't get to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({

    url : 'http://157.230.17.221/test/test',
    type : 'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data) {              
        alert('Data: '+data);
    },
    error : function(request,error)
    {
        alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request)+JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
</script>

</head>

</html>
```

The call goes to the error alert with a `{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}` response. I'd be happy to get any suggestions on how to format the response, any modifications to this code that work or any alternatives to ajax that would do the job. The goal is to inject the response into the html.

Comment: You'll need to show the backend code and configuration; that's where CORS is configured. The client is somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` this should be in your `server`, not in the `client`

Comment: If the status is 0 then your Developer Tools Console should give you an error message explaining why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is fine:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 15 Jul 2019 22:34:45 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 26
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Cookie, Set-Cookie, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Cache-Control: public, max-age=10

{"name":"john","age":"33"}
```

I suspect that the page you're loading this on is HTTPS, but your API service only supports HTTP.  I can reproduce the issue via JSFiddle.  (Link in the comments, because Stack Overflow won't let me put it here.)

When you have a page that uses HTTPS, any XHR or Fetch requests must also use HTTPS.  Your service only responds to HTTP, which causes this error to occur.

To fix it, enable HTTPS on your API service as well.

Comment: Thanks! If i access your code with http://jsfiddle.net/6uLj3bs9/ the data shows up fine. You nailed it!