# Fetch HTTP-resource from an HTTPS-hosted website not working

Tags: javascript, web-worker

This issue is related only to websites hosted on HTTPS, which need to make requests to an HTTP-endpoint (seems to be working in Chrome, however).

The following code was used:
HTML:

```html
<button id="fetchButton">click me</button>

<script>
  var worker = new Worker("/worker.js");
  var button = document.getElementById("fetchButton");

  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    myWorker.postMessage("");
  });

  worker.onmessage = response => {
    console.log("message from worker");
    console.log(response.data);
  }
</script>
```

Worker:

```js
onmessage = async function (event) {
  const result = await (await fetch("http://localhost:3000/something")).json();
  this.postMessage(result);
}
```

When hosting this website on an HTTPS-enabled website, I get back a response in Chrome, but not in Firefox, but I couldn't find any more specific docs about this one. Is there a way of getting this to work in Firefox, too? Or is this behavior (Firefox) the correct one, on how to deal with mixed-content? The above code works on both Chrome and Firefox, when hosted locally without HTTPS, so it's probably related to serving the website over HTTPS or not.

Comment: You must get back some kind of response, check the browser devtools network tab.

Comment: @James i did check the dev-tools. I get back a response in Firefox if I serve it locally, but not if it's served somewhere over HTTPS. In Chrome, on the other hand, it's working in any case. On Firefox it seems like the web worker is not even being triggered, as I can't see any hit on the Endpoint itself, when serving it over HTTPS.

Comment: @IvanSieder You will need to make those endpoints HTTPS.  I answered a similar question here yesterday:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57047971/362536  I suspect you're getting the same error in Firefox.

Comment: @Brad the problem is, that those endpoints are receipt printers, which do not support any kind of HTTPS. I was initially thinking about installing a local utility application, but as it seems, in Firefox, even localhost won't work inside web workers, if it's not https.

Comment: You'll need some sort of local proxy then, as you've suggested.  A lot of the well-intentioned browser policies are really breaking use cases like yours.  :-/

Comment: @Brad that won't fix the issue sadly, as Firefox seemingly also doesn't allow localhost calls from https to http.

Comment: I mean, run an HTTPS server locally.  You'll need a certificate and all that.  :-/